# What's the best way to reattach a piece of siding?

Tags: repair, siding

I just noticed I have a piece of [HardiePlank®](http://www.jameshardie.com/homeowner/products_siding_hardieplankLapSiding.py) that is coming off the side of my house. What would be the best way to reattach it?  I have no experience with the stuff, but it seems like a simple diy fix.

It's just my luck that the piece that's starting to come off is also at one of the highest points on the house.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the installation instructions](http://www.jameshardie.com/pdf/install/hardieplank-hz5.pdf)

Face nail with a 2" 6d or siding nail.

For good measure you could put a dab of matching color caulk behind the nail head before you nail it all the way down.